# iToggle for jQuery : Not working Properly

Tags: jquery, plugins, toggle, easing

i am trying to use [jQuery iToggle Plugin](http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/) for one of my projects. But it does not seem to work correctly. Let's get to the code first, then i'd explain the problems.

The HTML `<head>` section ::

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load=admin-bar,wp-admin&amp;ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="thickbox-css" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="myth_admin_stylesheet-css" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/css/mythadmin.css?ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="myth_itoggle_stylesheet-css" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/css/engage.itoggle.css?ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="myth_admin_colorpicker_stylesheet-css" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css?ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="colors-css" href="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css?ver=3.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load=jquery,utils&amp;ver=3.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/js/jquery.easing.js?ver=3.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js?ver=3.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/js/engage.itoggle.js?ver=3.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/projects/mythadmin/wp-content/themes/mythadmin/mythadmin/js/mythadmin.js?ver=3.4.2"></script>
```

Here All the Files are being loaded properly without any `404s`.

The HTML body::

```
<div class="myth_option_container toggle">
    <label for="test_cb">Test Checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test_cb" name="test_cb">
</div>
```

Calling the iToggle function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Initialize iToggle Checkboxes
   $('input#test_cb').iToggle({
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        speed: 300
    });
});
```

The above code is being called from the `mythadmin.js` file which is included in the end in the `head` section.

This does not seem to work at all, i have no errors in the console, all files are being loaded properly but i am not able to see the toggle button.

Though if i target the `input's parent container`, i am able to see the toggle box and switch it on and off but without the `easing` effect (for some reason).

So say if i change `$('input#test_cb')` to `$('div.toggle')` it works (with no easing effect at all).

Questions:

1. Why does this not work when i bind it directly to a checkbox input.
2. Why is the easing effect not working even when `easing.js` is being loaded properly.

Thanks in advance for your time and help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same problem here. Try older version of jQuery (1.4.2-min) and it works fine... doesn't seem to work well with 1.8.2 though...

EDITED: [iToogle](https://github.com/pshiryaev/iToggle/downloads) < this version of iToggle should work with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: i switched to iPhone Style Checkboxes library [http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/] and it works as expected with the latest version of jQuery :)

Comment: Amyth: This requires commercial licensing unfortunatelly.